# plot wont load : Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

hello ive been trying to get correlation between tables,and im trying to get a graph with matplotlib,but it gives error TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float and the graph wont load

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
usd_price = pd.read_csv("data_usd.csv")
gold_price = pd.read_csv("emas_.csv")
minyak = pd.read_csv("minyak_brent.csv")
minyak.head()
merged_data = pd.concat([usd_price, gold_price], axis=1)
merged_data.columns
merged_data.shape
merged_data = merged_data.set_index('month')
merged_data.head()
plt.matshow(merged_data)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) (part ugly in first answer) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.